# Close current tab by a html button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to close the current tab of my program by a button which I created in HTML and gave him a click event so I want to close the tab in js by doing an onclick but when I click on my button nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-light" id="closebtn" onclick="closeBtnClicked"> Close </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

And this is my js function:

```
function closeBtnClicked(){
    window.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `onclick` attribute must contain a function call, not the function name. Simply change `onclick="closeBtnClicked"` to `onclick="closeBtnClicked()"`.

See [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) for examples and a definition of the onclick attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code. The first and more obvious one is that your `onclick` attribute value is missing the `()` after the function. Because of this, your function never actually got called.

However, when you fix this problem, you notice the other one: Calling the function `window.close()` in most modern browser will fail, if the window was not also opened by the same script (e.g. using the `open()` function).

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) this is a security precaution, although I don't understand how a script closing its own tab could be exploited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: by just calling `close` and onclick is a function so change that to closeBtnClicked().

```js
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    close();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="javascript:close_window();">close</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot "()", it's

```
onclick="closeBtnClicked()"
```